# Multi-level push menu is too heavy for browser when resizing window

Tags: css, mobile, menu, user-experience, multi-level

when I made a multi-level menu for mobile phones, I found that having several levels behind the horizon y coordinates with the width of each level 100% is quite demanding for the browser when changing the width of the window.

I do not want to use any plugin, I just want to have my simple code, so do you have any advice on how to predict each level hidden behind the horizon before it emits to prevent the browser from changing the window width in the meantime? Because each level changes its width due to its width: 100%.

Levels have also transition, in another class.

So basicly every level have this setup:

```
#nav-menu, #nav-menu .nav-level {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Some of your css here is redundant, so you could easily simplify it. Additionally, to answer your question correctly, it would help to include some markup to show what your page structure is. It's unclear what the problem might be based only on what you shared here.

I'd recommend creating a codepen with a basic example of your markup and CSS so you can get more specific feedback.

Comment: I send all code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518062/multi-level-push-menu-is-too-heavy-demanding-for-browsers

Comment: Since you opened a second duplicate question, you should probably close this one as a duplicate.